# How to run script on build host (not docker container) during gitlab CI pipeline

Tags: gitlab-ci

I'm new to Gitlab (and YML files, and just about everything else in this project ...), and want to add some script to the build pipeline to automate release file generation.

I added a few script lines to the branch's release section in gitlab-ci.yml, and can see they're generally doing what I want in the console output to the Gitlab UI. But, after a bit of head scratching I now realise the build itself is executed within a docker instance, which explains why I can't see the release file on the Gitlab host machine.

Is there a way of executing script from the YML file on the Gitlab host, as opposed to within the build container?

Comment: For what it's worth to anybody else, I ended up mounting a volume between the host and build docker instance, and writing to the file that way. This has to be done per project it seems, in config.toml.

Answer (score 5):

It depends on the [executor type](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/#selecting-the-executor) of the [Gitlab Runner](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/) where the scripts are executed.

If the jobs are executed on a runner with a [docker executor](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/executors/docker.html), each job will be run in a new container.

If the jobs are executed on a runner with a [Shell executor](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/executors/shell.html) the jobs will be executed directly on the runner machine.

BTW, it is not advised to have your runners on the same machine where you host your Gitlab server. Especially, runners with Shell executor. It compromises resiliency and scalability. A CI/CD job could break the entire host and make your gitlab server unavailable.